# With hive's complex struct data type, how to write query with where clause

Tags: struct, types, hive

I've have following hive table with complex data type, STRUCT. Can you please help writing hive query with where clause for specific city?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user_t (
 name      STRING,
 id        BIGINT,
 isFTE     BOOLEAN,
 role      VARCHAR(64),
 salary    DECIMAL(8,2),
 phones    ARRAY<INT>,
 deductions MAP<STRING, FLOAT>,
 address   ARRAY<STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>>,
 others    UNIONTYPE<FLOAT,BOOLEAN,STRING>,
 misc      BINARY
 )
```

I'm able to use STRUCT data type in select clause but not able to use same in where clause.

Working:

```
select address.city from user_t;
```

Not working:

```
select address.city from user_t where address.city = 'XYZ'
```

Documentation says it has limitation while using group by or where clause and gave a solution as well. But I didn't understand it clearly.
Link: [Documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_complex_types.html#complex_types_limits)

Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Hive or Impala?

Comment: Show error message

Comment: I'm using beeline.  Error Massage: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 1:48 Argument type mismatch 'city': The 1st argument of EQUAL  is expected to a primitive type, but list is found (state=42000,code=10016)

Comment: Please verify that your create table statement compiles without errors.

Comment: Verified. Table got created. I had to change deductions column from MAP<CHAR, FLOAT> to MAP<STRING, FLOAT>.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz pl note edit's in data type of column address. My apologies, it was overlooked by me in original post.

Comment: On top of that you have tagged your post with `hive` but you gave a link to `Impala` documentation. Which one of them is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Demo

```
create table user_t 
(
    id        bigint
   ,address   array<struct<street:string, city:string, state:string, zip:int>>
)
;

insert into user_t 

    select  1
           ,array
            (
                named_struct('street','street_1','city','city_1','state','state_1','zip',11111)
               ,named_struct('street','street_2','city','city_1','state','state_1','zip',11111)
               ,named_struct('street','street_3','city','city_3','state','state_3','zip',33333)
            )

    union all

    select  2
           ,array
            (
                named_struct('street','street_4','city','city_4','state','state_4','zip',44444)
               ,named_struct('street','street_5','city','city_5','state','state_5','zip',55555)
            )
;
```

#### Option 1: explode

```
select  u.id
       ,a.*

from    user_t as u
        lateral view explode(address) a as details

where   details.city = 'city_1'
;
```

---

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                               details                               |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"street":"street_1","city":"city_1","state":"state_1","zip":11111} |
|  1 | {"street":"street_2","city":"city_1","state":"state_1","zip":11111} |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Option 2: inline

```
select  u.id
       ,a.*

from    user_t as u
        lateral view inline(address) a

where   a.city = 'city_1'
;
```

---

```
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------+
| id |  street  |  city  |  state  |  zip  |
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------+
|  1 | street_1 | city_1 | state_1 | 11111 |
|  1 | street_2 | city_1 | state_1 | 11111 |
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------+
```

#### Option 3: self join

```
select  u.*

from            user_t as u

        join   (select  distinct
                        u.id

                from    user_t as u
                        lateral view inline(address) a

                where   a.city = 'city_1'
                ) as u2

        on      u2.id = u.id
;
```

---

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                                                                                                    address                                                                                                    |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"street":"street_1","city":"city_1","state":"state_1","zip":11111},{"street":"street_2","city":"city_1","state":"state_1","zip":11111},{"street":"street_3","city":"city_3","state":"state_3","zip":33333}] |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```